# Applying if and & if or with grepl to get multiple responses based on conditions

Tags: r, if-statement, grepl

I am trying to create an if-and-or statement with multiple responses.

A sample dataset is as follows (my actual data does not have columns next to each other and has a lot more responses:

```
hairdf=data.frame(
id=c(1:5),
  drug1=c("etoh*","hhh","etoh","hhhh","blank"),
  source1=c("no blood","yes","some blood","nothing","blank"),
  con1=c("5","6","4","2","0"),
  unit1=c("g/l","cm/l","g/km","j/nm","t/mm"),
  drug2=c("hhh","etoh*","hhh","etoh","blank"),
  source1=c("no ","yes blood","some","nothing","blank"),
  con1=c("6","7","8","9","1"),
  unit1=c("cm/l","g/km","j/nm","t/mm","g/l"))
```

I am trying to create 2 new columns that will return the conc and units if 1) drug 1 is etoh or etoh* and source1 has the word blood or if 1) drug 2 is etoh or etoh* and source2 has the word blood.

I have tried the following code but am coming up with an error:

```
    wordetoh <-c("etoh", "etoh*")

hairdf<-hairdf %>%
    mutate(etohconc=if_else(
        drug1 %in% wordetoh & grepl("blood",source1), con1 | 
drug2 %in% wordetoh & grepl("blood",source2), con2,
        ""))

hairdf<-hairdf %>%
mutate(etohunit=if_else(
            drug1 %in% wordetoh & grepl("blood",source1), unit1 |
     drug2 %in% wordetoh & grepl("blood",source2), unit 2,
            ""))
```

Based on my data, the new columns should have the following responses

etohconc: 5,7,4, *blank*, *blank*

etohunit: g/l, g/km, g/km, *blank*, *blank*.

Comment: Yes it was misspelled there, thanks for noticing, I've changed that! But i think there are still other mistakes in the code.

Comment: What should happen if both are true? Is it possible both drug1 and drug2 meet those criteria in a given row?

Comment: Some of the column names are duplicated.  Are the second set supposed to be `source2`, `con2`, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that some of the columns in the sample dataset are misnamed and should actually look like this:

```
hairdf=data.frame(
  id=c(1:5),
  drug1=c("etoh*","hhh","etoh","hhhh","blank"),
  source1=c("no blood","yes","some blood","nothing","blank"),
  con1=c("5","6","4","2","0"),
  unit1=c("g/l","cm/l","g/km","j/nm","t/mm"),
  drug2=c("hhh","etoh*","hhh","etoh","blank"),
  source2=c("no ","yes blood","some","nothing","blank"),
  con2=c("6","7","8","9","1"),
  unit2=c("cm/l","g/km","j/nm","t/mm","g/l"))
```

It sounds like your situation is one where you don't just have multiple conditions; you want different outcomes depending on those different conditions.  For example, I infer that if drug 1 meets the conditions, then you want the concentration and unit of drug 1; but if drug 2 meets the conditions, then you want the concentration and unit of drug 2.  `if_else()` doesn't do this; it takes a single boolean (which can be arbitrarily complex) and returns one of exactly two outcomes: one outcome if the boolean evaluates to true, and another if it evaluates to false.

`case_when()` is a good option for your situation.  (Nested `if_else()` would work too, but I find `case_when()` much easier to read.)  Give it a series of condition:outcome pairs, and it can handle all three cases you're interested in:

```
library(tidyverse)
hairdf = hairdf %>%
  mutate(etohconc = case_when(drug1 %in% wordetoh & grepl("blood", source1) ~ con1,
                              drug2 %in% wordetoh & grepl("blood", source2) ~ con2,
                              T ~ NA_character_),
         etohunit = case_when(drug1 %in% wordetoh & grepl("blood", source1) ~ unit1,
                              drug2 %in% wordetoh & grepl("blood", source2) ~ unit2,
                              T ~ NA_character_))
```